# Aggregate RDD values per key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, rdd

I have RDD in key,value structure (someKey,(measure1,measure2)). I grouped by the key and now I want to aggregate the values for each key.

```
val RDD1 : RDD[(String,(Int,Int))]
RDD1.groupByKey()
```

the result I need is:

```
key: avg(measure1), avg(measure2), max(measure1), max(measure2), min(measure1), min(measure2), count(*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [avoid groupByKey](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)! You should use `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey`. We will use [`aggregateByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions). This function will transform values for each key: `RDD[(K, V)] => RDD[(K, U)]`. It needs zero value of type `U` and knowledge how to merge `(V, U) => U` and `(U, U) => U`. I simplified your example a little bit and want to get: `key:  avg(measure1), avg(measure2), min(measure1), min(measure2), count(*)`

```
  val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(("a", (11, 1)), ("a",(12, 3)), ("b",(10, 1))))
  rdd1
    .aggregateByKey((0.0, 0.0, Int.MaxValue, Int.MaxValue, 0))(
      {
        case ((sum1, sum2, min1, min2, count1), (v1, v2)) =>
          (sum1 + v1, sum2 + v2, v1 min min1, v2 min min2, count1+1)
      }, 
      {
        case ((sum1, sum2, min1, min2, count),
          (otherSum1, otherSum2, otherMin1, otherMin2, otherCount)) =>
          (sum1 + otherSum1, sum2 + otherSum2, 
           min1 min otherMin1, min2 min otherMin2, count + otherCount)
      }
    )
    .map {
      case (k, (sum1, sum2, min1, min2, count1)) => (k, (sum1/count1, sum2/count1, min1, min2, count1))
    }
    .collect()
```

giving

```
   (a,(11.5,2.0,11,1,2)), (b,(10.0,1.0,10,1,1))
```